# Find the magnitdue of a vector along a specific heading

Tags: trigonometry

I've gotten some seemingly conflicting answers about this, so I'm hoping someone can help straighten this out for me.

Given a vector of components East/West (u) and North/South (v), how do I find the magnitude of a specific bearing.

I have an Eastward component of 3 and a Southward component of -5

```
Speed=sqrt(3^2+(-5)^2)
Speed=5.83

theta<-atan2(v,u)
theta<- -59.0362
```

In compass bearings

```
Direction=90-theta
Direction=149.0362°
```

So I have a speed of 5.83 and a direction of 149°

So given this information, now I want to know the magnitude of the component vector of 120°.

I'm not sure if I need to be looking into vector rotation, or some other trig. I've found the following different answers:

```
New Speed= cos(149-120)

New Speed= v*cos(180-120) + u*sin(180-120)

New Speed= u*sin(120)-v*cos(120)
```

Which all have different outcomes so I'm not sure which one is right.

BTW-This is not homework, I'm trying to isolate flow speeds in a single specific direction. So even though my raw data has a range of speeds and directions, in the end I only want data on the speed of the vector at 120°

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in angle between the two vectors, call it $\theta$, is what you need to use.  Specifically, $\cos$ is used for the vector that forms a "V" shape with the original where $\theta$ is the angle between them.  Given $s$ is the old speed and $n$ is the new speed, then $n=s\cos(\theta)$, because the new speed is merely a component of the old speed.  Also, $m=s\sin(\theta)$ is the complement of the new speed (and is perpendicular to it) and the two together make up your original vector, i.e., $\sqrt{m^2+n^2}=s$.

Note that this transformation applies equally whether "newangle-oldangle" or "oldangle-newangle" is used as the value of $\theta$.  The reason this is true is twofold:

- $\cos \theta = \cos -\theta$, so you are guaranteed to get the same value either way
- $\sin -\theta = -\sin \theta$, so the magnitude or absolute-value obtained is the same either way.

If you needed to find a direction, then the sign of $\sin\theta$ would make a difference in which angle you were picking.  As it is, you have chosen your new angle (i.e., $120$°), so you don't need to worry about this piece.

Comment: Great answer!- Is there ever a case where I would want to use n=sin(θ) to get my desired magnitude?

Comment: For the described scenario, no.  $\cos$ handles the "adjacent : hypotenuse" ratio, where $\sin$ handles the "opposite : hypotenuse" ratio of the implicit triangle.  For your scenario, you have described the side "adjacent" to the "hypotenuse", which is to say that the new speed component is "adjacent" to the old speed component (the hypotenuse) relative to the angle between them ($\theta$).  You may already be familiar with the "soh-cah-toa" mnemonic way of remembering these ratios.

Comment: I said "adjacent to the old speed component" where I meant "adjacent to the angle".  Then it actually makes sense to say that $\sin$ applies to the side "opposite the angle".

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to project your speed vector on a given direction.  Let $\vec s=(s_x,s_y)$ be the speed vector, and $\vec d=(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ be a unit vector in the direction of interest.  Then the length of the projection of $\vec s$ on $\vec d$ is $\vec s \cdot \vec d$, the dot product.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I'm following your abbreviations. Are you saying s=(5.83*5.83) and d=(cos(149-120)*sin(149-120))?

Comment: No, $\vec s=(3,-5), \vec d=(\cos 120^\circ,\sin 120^\circ)$, so $\vec s \cdot \vec d=3 \cdot (-0.5) + (-5) \cdot (\frac 12 \sqrt 3) \approx -5.83$

Comment: Your angular orientation is not standard for mathematics.  Usually $0^\circ$ is right, along the $+x$ axis, increasing counterclockwise.  Your $0^\circ$ is up (North) increasing clockwise.  This means $\vec d$ should be $(\sin \theta, \cos \theta)$ instead.

Comment: So $\vec s \cdot \vec d=3\cdot (\frac 12 \sqrt 3)+(-5)\cdot (-0.5)\approx 5.098$