# How, in simplest possible terms, does one determine the speed an object is traveling along a given vector?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

Say I have a two-dimensional vector *v*, which is the velocity of a rocket. I also have the vector *f*, which is a direction vector (with magnitude 1), that represents the direction the rocket is facing.

Given that I know *f* and *v*, how can I determine the speed the rocket is traveling along *f*? In other words, if *f = v*, the answer would be the magnitude of *v*. If *f* is perpendicular to *v*, the answer would be zero. How can I get the answer for arbitrary *f* and *v*, in basic algebraic terms?

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497083/find-the-magnitdue-of-a-vector-along-a-specific-heading) seems to be a duplicate, but I honestly can't tell. I don't have a solid understanding of any more than basic algebra and a few essential concepts of trigonometry. Can someone explain how solve this problem without assuming more than a grade-school level of mathematics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is the vector dot product between $f$ and $v$:-

$speed=|v||f|\cos(\theta)=v\cdot f$

where $\theta$ is the angle between vectors $v$ and $f$, and $|v|$ and $|f|$ are the magnitude of vectors $v$ and $f$ respectively.

Note that if the vectors are perpendicular, $\theta=\pi/2$, so that $\cos(\theta)=0$, resulting in zero speed. If, however, $f$ and $v$ coincide, then $\theta=0$, leading to $\cos(\theta)=1$, so that the speed is $|v|$, the magnitude of $v$, as $|f|$ is equal to $1$.

If we represent the vectors in the following manner (assuming a $3$-D system of coordinates):-

$$v=v_x\mathbf{x}+v_y\mathbf{y}+v_z\mathbf{z}$$

$$f=f_x\mathbf{x}+f_y\mathbf{y}+f_z\mathbf{z}$$

The magnitude of the vectors will be:-

$$|v|=\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2}$$

$$|f|=\sqrt{f_x^2+f_y^2+f_z^2}=1$$

The dot product is given by

$$v\cdot f=v_xf_x+v_yf_y+v_zf_z=|v||f|\cos(\theta)$$

Thus

$$\cos(\theta)=\frac{v\cdot f}{|v||f|}=\frac{v_xf_x+v_yf_y+v_zf_z}{\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2}}$$

Comment: So do I want the dot product of f and v, or do I want the magnitude of v times the magnitude of f times the cosine of the angle between them? Or are they equal? And how do I find theta?

Comment: The geometric definition of the dot product between two Euclidean vectors $x$ and $y$ is the same as the magnitude of $v$ times the magnitude of $f$ times the cosine of the angle between them. So if you want the speed, you don't need to know the angle between them - I'll edit my answer.